# Listbox Items Name Linked To Another Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, controls

So the following code is adding a picturebox for each item that has been entered into a listbox.

```
    Dim x As Integer = 790
    Dim y As Integer = 91
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
        Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
        MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(x, y)
        MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(12, 12)
        MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
        MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Warning1
        x += 0
        y += 13

    Next i
```

I have another process running that will create a file for each item in the listbox and have that file named for each item.

Exampe: I added 20 items to the listbox and I'll have 20 pictureboxes. If I want to remove say item 15, I also want to remove the picturebox next to it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text of the `ListBox` items are unique, then you can use that to link the two together, otherwise, you'll need some other property on each item which can be used as a unique key.  What you can then do is to set the `Name` property of each `PictureBox` control to the unique key value of the matching item in the list.  For instance:

```
Dim key As String = ListBoxItems(i).ToString()
...
MyPictureBox.Name = "pic" + key
```

Then, when you want to get the matching `PictureBox` control for a given item, you could do something like this:

```
Dim p As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + item.ToString()), PictureBox)
```

(Where `item` is the item from the `ListBox`)  To delete it, you would just do this:

```
Me.Controls.Remove(p)
p.Dispose()
```

Comment: Yeah all items in the listbox will be unique. Thanks for your suggestion...I'll see what I can make out of it.

Comment: Question...where is the `item.ToString` coming from?

Comment: I'm just supposing that when you go to remove an item to the list that you have a reference to the item you want to remove.  It may be, at that point you have an index to it, in which case it would be `ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()` instead of `item.ToString()`.  Or, perhaps, at that point the item is selected, in which case it would be `ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()`.  Since you didn't post that part of your code, I couldn't give a more specific example.

Comment: After looking back over your example, I found what part you were referring to, thanks again!

Comment: I posted a slightly different question, regarding how to change the picturebox instead of deleting them. Its based on the `FileSystemWatcher`. Could you take a peek?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465968/changing-a-linked-picturebox-control-when-a-file-exists