# How to find and update a matching control once a file exists

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, file-io, controls

I have written a WinForm project which displays a `ListBox` containing a list of file names.  When the user clicks a submit button, the application dynamically loads and displays one `PictureBox` control for each file and then waits while they are processed.  As PDF files are generated for each one, the matching `PictureBox` for that file needs to be updated to display an image.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub ButtonSubmit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonSubmit.Click

    Dim x As Integer = 790
    Dim y As Integer = 91
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim key As String = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()

        'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
        Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
        MyPictureBox.Name = "pic" + key
        MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(x, y)
        MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(12, 12)
        MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
        MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Warning1
        ToolTipSpooling.SetToolTip(MyPictureBox, "Creating PDF...")
        x += 0
        y += 13

    Next i

    Call CheckPDFs()

End Sub

Public Sub CheckPDFs()
    Dim ListboxTicketIDs = (From i In ListBox1.Items).ToArray()

    For Each Item In ListboxTicketIDs
        Dim ID = Item.ToString

        Dim Watcher As New FileSystemWatcher()
        Watcher.Path = "C:\Temp\"
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.Attributes)
        Watcher.Filter = ID + ".pdf"

        AddHandler Watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged

        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)

    Dim p As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + ListBox1.Items.ToString()), PictureBox)
    p.Image = My.Resources.Ok1

End Sub
```

I'm having trouble changing the `PictureBox` to a different picture once the item(s) listed in the listbox are present, based on the `FileSystemWatcher`.  For instance, the files are not always created in the same order as they exist in the `ListBox`.

**EDIT**

Working code below.

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents Watcher As FileSystemWatcher

Public Sub CheckPDFs()
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Watcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
        Watcher.SynchronizingObject = Me
        Watcher.Path = "C:\Temp\"
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
        Watcher.Filter = "*.pdf"

        Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Watcher_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles Watcher.Changed

    Dim key As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.Name)
    Dim p As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + key), PictureBox)
    p.Image = My.Resources.Ok

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
    TextBox1.Text = ""

    Dim x As Integer = 5
    Dim y As Integer = 5
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        Dim key As String = ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()

        'adds picturebox for as many listbox items added
        Dim MyPictureBox As New PictureBox()
        MyPictureBox.Name = "pic" + key
        MyPictureBox.Location = New Point(x, y)
        MyPictureBox.Size = New Size(15, 15)
        MyPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        Me.Controls.Add(MyPictureBox)
        MyPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.Info
        x += 0
        y += 18

    Next i

    Call CheckPDFs()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create multiple file watchers.  You just need a single file watcher to watch for any changes to the folder.  I would recommend declaring it as a private field at the top of your form using the `WithEvents` keyword so you don't have to worry about adding and removing event handlers.

Next, when the watcher raises the changed event, you can get the file name of the file that changed by looking at the properties of the event args object.  You need to get the name of the file that changed and then use the file name as the key to finding the matching picture box control.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private WithEvents Watcher As FileSystemWatcher

    Public Sub CheckPDFs()
        Watcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
        Watcher.Path = "C:\Temp\"
        Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes
        Watcher.Filter = "*.pdf"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Watcher_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles Watcher.Changed
        Dim key As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.Name)
        Dim p As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + key), PictureBox)
        p.Image = My.Resources.Ok1
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, since you say in a comment below that the file name will not be the same as the text in the listbox, but that it will merely *start* with that text, you could do something like this, instead:

```
Private Sub Watcher_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles Watcher.Changed
    Dim p As PictureBox = Nothing
    For Each item As Object In ListBox1.Items
        If e.Name.StartsWith(item.ToString()) Then
            p = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + item.ToString()), PictureBox)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        p.Image = My.Resources.Ok1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I reference the `i` in `Dim p As PictureBox = CType(Me.Controls("pic" + ListBox1.Items(i).ToString()), PictureBox)`? I must be doing something wrong as nothing is triggering.

Comment: If I add the for next statement, all images change regardless of which one is created...which goes back to my first question, how are you referencing the `i`.

Comment: Nevermind...if you fail, try try again..hahahaha. I fiugured out I needed a For Next statement when calling the CheckPDFs routine. Then I figured out the `i` needed to be the `key` that you setup in the `Watcher_Changed` routine. Edited my original with the working code...thanks again for your help!

Comment: OOPS!  I copied that part of your code from your example and forgot to update it.  It should be using the `key` variable instead of the item from the `ListBox`.  I fixed my answer so it should work now.  There's no reason to be doing a loop in the `Watcher` event because that event will be raised separately for every file that changes.

Comment: Just when you think everything works well, it doesn't. The file being created is not going to be the same name, but will in the beginning of the file the same thing I enter. Meaning I enter `12345` and click submit, a process will then create a PDF named `12345_Text_Here.pdf` so then the code blows up at `p.Image = My.Resources.Ok1`. Can I look for parts of the filename somehow?

Comment: I ended up adding `subkey = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(key, 6)` to take off all text after the key in the filename, since I only need X amount of characters from the left. Not sure if this is the best practice though.

Comment: Yes, that would be even better if you know that the first six characters is always the key.  However, I would recommend using `key.SubString(1, 6)` rather than the `Left` method.  The `Left` method should not really be used in new .NET applications.  It's mainly just there for backwards compatibility with VB6 code.